# How to write query for value not in range between field min and max

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve value that out of range refer to min column field and max field.
I have value field, min field and max field in my sql table.For e.g the value 40 is out of range between 50 and 60, so it need to show up, same with the value for 74 and 37.

```
Value   Min   Max

95      85    100
40      50     60
74      60     70
37      50     60
```

i have tried this code but it seems dont work.Thanks for any suggestion.

```
SELECT [value], [Min], [Max] FROM [A].[dbo].[VW_Process] WHERE (VW_Process.Value NOT BETWEEN VW_Process.Min AND VW_Process.Max)
```

Comment: Your columns are probably not a number datatype. Likely a char or varchar.

Comment: @ypercube - I'm getting the feeling you are right - this is such simple SQL that it should be working.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the datatype is varchar.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE NOT BETWEEN MIN AND MAX
```

I know this is what you first put in your OP, but my repro as follows shows it works

```
CREATE TABLE T1 
(
VAL INT,
MINVAL INT,
MAXVAL INT
)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(95,85,100)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(40,50,60)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(74,60,70)
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(37,50,60)

SELECT Val FROM T1 where VAL NOT BETWEEN MINVAL AND MAXVAL
```

Returns 3 rows - 40,74,37 - all are not between MIN and MAX, but does not return 95, which clearly is between 85 and 100

Comment: Isn't that the same as OP stated in the question?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried but it won't work, it will still show up value 95.

Answer (score 1):

That should do, in case yours does not work;

```
SELECT [value], [Min], [Max] 
FROM [A].[dbo].[VW_Process] 
WHERE Value < Min 
AND Value > Max
```

Comment: According to OP ***I need to retrieve value that out of range*** and you query returns records which are in range [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da445e/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT [value], [Min], [Max] 
FROM   [A].[dbo].[VW_Process]
WHERE  (Value NOT BETWEEN [Min] AND [Max])
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da445e/4)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jesuraja. I have tried but it won't work, it will still show up value 95.

Answer (score 0):

So, we don't know types of your fields, try this:

```
SELECT value, Min, Max 
FROM   [A].[dbo].[VW_Process]
WHERE  cast(Value as int) NOT BETWEEN cast(Min as int) AND cast(Max as int)
```